# How to increase contrast and color saturation when loading a model from gltf

Tags: three.js, gltf

Is it possible in this example https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_gltf.html increase the contrast of the model?

I use this approach to load my models and they come out unsaturated in colors, as if in a small haze (http://prntscr.com/txmihr). Can this be fixed? Thanks

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail about what you are trying to do, what you've tried, and what is or isn't working. This question does not currently have enough detail for others to help you.

Comment: I gave an example from the site threejs.org. Is it possible to make the result more contrasting and rich in colors?

Comment: You will want to look into topics like tonemapping, environment lighting, exposure, post-processing, and other renderer settings that three.js provides. Find three.js examples that look better than your own, and look at their code. There's no one quick answer to make an image look rich in color.

Answer (score 2):

I came upon this post while researching a problem I had with a mapped texture looking washed out (unsaturated, hazy etc) on my project.

I'm not an expert in THREE or REACT THREE FIBER, but I wanted to share my solution in case there are others on the same search...

There is an issue related to sRGB encoding in THREE. In RTF try using the `linear` and `flat` props on your `<Canvas/>`:

```
<Canvas
  linear
  flat
>
...
</Canvas>
```

https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/blob/master/markdown/api.md?plain=1#L50-L51